# Mongolab offline buffer?

Tags: java, android, embedded-database

I have an app that sends data to a mongolab database, making it possible for other devices to see the data when connected to the internet.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to create a "buffer" of some sort that can gather the data when I'm offline and sync with the database when one gets back online?

The application I am referring to is called Nightscout, and it is used to visualize and monitor blood glucose values for diabetics. The app is open  source and I want to modify it so that you can monitor and log the data without having to be connected to the internet. The goal is sending blood glucose values to fitness devices like Garmin etc, making monitoring easy while being active.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Asking for software library recommendations is unfortunately not [on-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and your problem as described is very general. I'm not familiar with Nightscout or the devices in question, but this sounds like a question better discussed within the Nightscout developer community so you can get suggestions that fit in with the [Nightscout architecture](http://www.nightscout.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/HowDoYouGetYourCGM-300dpi-092116-evolve4.png) and the device(s) you plan to support.

Comment: I suspect glucose monitoring devices will already have some sort of offline buffer but you could perhaps build one into the Nightscout Android client as well, if needed. [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) is typically used as a local database on Android, but depending on the data formats that Nightscout works with there may be simpler solutions like flat files. Although you mention MongoDB, it looks this is the backing data store for the Nightscout API but the apps appears to post via the API rather than directly.